# Is there a faster way to get the dimensions of a jpg image from a file than using System.Drawing.Image.FromFile

Tags: c#, .net, jpeg, image-size

Width and Height of an image inside a jpg file can be retrieved by reading all file data into an Image.

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("a.jpg");
var w = img.Width
var h = img.Height
```

This is costly however and if only width and height are needed, there might be a better way.

So I wonder if there is a less resource intensive way to get the image dimensions. In my (common) scenario, the jpg is uploaded to the web server and the web application shall just get width and height and store that. I thought, the jpg file format might have width and height as easy readable metadata and if so, someone knows how to access it.

Comment: You could read the file metadata.  You'll have to read the file as a binary stream and look up the standard re: the header.  Not sure if any libraries exist to do this for you.

Comment: @bradley you are right. the link is helpful. its a bit tougher than expected, but anyway, great answer there. thx

Comment: The problem is the answer linked to is WRONG for JPEG. Original poster should repost but only with the JPEG tag so you don't get zapped by a bunch of YAHOOs who don't know what they are doing.

Comment: I am limited here but the problem with the "answer" is that it only handles a limited set of JPEG files. First look for an SOI market to be sure its a JPEG stream (Not just a JFIF stream as in the "answer"). Then you need to scan the stream for a SOF marker (there are three types-the "answer" only has one). The image size is in the SOF marker in big endian format.

Comment: very helpful, thx a lot! will digg into the jpeg file format soon. will use System.Drawing.Image.FromFile to test if my results from file reading are correct.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to parse the file header directly instead of constructing an image, the width and height are in there
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure

Comment: thx. looks like width and height are indirectly specified, as Density units, X and Y density.